# Syncing Files between orgs (e.g. via Salesforce Connect's Cross-Org Adapter?)

Tags: integration, attachment, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, lightning-connect

Can anyone suggest a high-level solution for the use case of syncing Files between orgs (one-way is fine)?  Preferably something that can  be quickly POC'd.

For us, Plan A would be to use the Salesforce Connect Cross-Org Adapter for **Files (ContentDocument/Links)** (or **Attachments**) since we're already using it. (I've been told that Files & Attachments aren't supported with the Cross-Org Adapter, but I can't find any documentation on this to verify, e.g. here: [Considerations for Salesforce Connect—Cross-Org Adapter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.xorg_considerations.htm&type=5)).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using MuleSoft or Heroku, if you are willing to customize heavily.

Sometimes, out of the box solutions, that Salesforce provides end up having a lot of limitations creating more roadblocks. I'd suggest to invest some time researching and comparing the features of the below options with the features and limitations of Salesforce Connect-Cross-Org Adapter.

That should make things crystal clear for you.

Here are some links you can use.

- MuleSoft Org to Org Bi-directional sync for [Account](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.templates/template-sfdc2sfdc-account-bidirectional-sync/) and [Oppty](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.templates/template-sfdc2sfdc-opportunity-bidirectional-sync/) objects.

  - You'd have to create multiple flows in MuleSoft for all the objects you'd want to sync.
- [Heroku Cross Org Data Synchronization](https://medium.com/salesforce-architects/heroku-pattern-cross-org-data-synchronization-addcaa2c970a)

Comment: Mulesoft can easily achieve this but i would look further to other iPAAS and middleware solutions as well to see which one fits your needs best